# Overdetermined linear system with the solution constrained to zeros on the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking to solve an overdetermined linear system with the constraint that the solution matrix should have zeros on the diagonal:
$X A = X$, where $A$ is a matrix of unknown coefficients, with the constraint that the diagonal should be zero, and $X$ is a matrix of shape $[m,n]$ with $m>n>1$ representing $n$ time series with $m$ samples in each time series.

I realize that I can solve this problem by taking out 1 time series from the set at a time and find any correlation between that particular time series and the rest, and repeat that process n times. (each time I do this would give me $n-1$ coefficients in $A$).

However, I can't help but feel there must be a smarter solution that allows this to be done all at once.

Comment: As indicated by the answer, you should define in which sense you want to solve $XA=X$ or if there are additionnal assumptions on $X$ or $A$. As currently written, the problem is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your question as written is impossible, let $X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $A  \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 1}.$ If $XA = X,$ it must be the case that $A = (1).$ Can you specify what you mean by zeros on the diagonal? If we know that $X$ does not have full column rank, it is potentially possible to do what you said.

Edit: $X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $A  \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}.$
Let $Id_2$ be the identity matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}.$
If $XA = X$, this implies that $Id_2A = Id_2 \implies A = Id_2.$

Comment: I should have specified that n>1

Comment: The case that $n > 1$ doesn't change anything. You should consider if $X$ has full column rank.

Comment: If you assume that $X$ doesn't have full column rank, google "singular value decomposition." It should follow from that.

Comment: X should not have zero rows, each row can be viewed as another example in which case adding rows with only zeros corresponds to the same solution as those rows removed. So the case that you have made is a case where m=n, and hence is not an overdetermined system.

Comment: So yes I agree that for the specific X you have chosen the system doesn't make much sense if you want to solve it for A with a zero diagonal, but for a general overdetermined system it will make sense.

Comment: For any overdetermined system with full column rank, you get the 'degenerate' solutions I listed above. I added a row of zeros to make it easier for me to write, but you should check that you can put anything in for the third row to get a solution. Again, I implore you, the case you're looking for is when the column rank of $X$ is not full, which you haven't specified in the problem.